# Power Bi data source, optimal query option: copy, duplicate or reference?

Tags: reference, duplicates, copy, powerbi, powerquery

I have a PBI file, in which I made a power query with several steps (such as merging two files).

I would like to produce several output files originating from this query, but specific steps for these files (I made a series of specific change to the data in these queries).

If I refresh my PBI file, I would like that all the queries from the original one to the three ones originating from this one get impacted.

I would also like to have impacts on the three other queries if I add a new step in the original query.

So far I used copy: 
I took my original query, I did a right click and simply used the "copy" option. However, this is duplicating the previously merged files used to create the query at the same time.

I see that there is also the option "Duplicate" and "reference" in Power BI.

I tried doing some research and I read the following on "Duplicate":

"*Duplicate copies a query with all the applied steps of it as a new query; an exact copy.*"

For me this seemed exactly that same as a "copy", I thus expected that I would get a copy of the previously merged files when I duplicated the query. But no. I tested it and only the selected query got duplicated.

When I did the test for "reference" however, my query appeared, only the result this time, (not the data use to create it), but it had no steps. When I try to click on "source", I cannot "see" the source.

[image]

I am thus puzzled as to the best way forward, and more broadly the best cases and practices to adopt.

What option could I choose enabling PBI to operate the same steps each time I refresh my source, i.e merging the two files and then doing a series of specific steps on three copies of my source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want to do the following:

1. Load `Universe 1` and `Universe 2`
2. Merge them into a single table `Merge1`
3. Create three new queries that reference `Merge1`
4. Create specific steps for each of the new queries

This way, each of the new queries starts at exactly the same place without having to load `Universe 1` and `Universe 2` three separate times.

If you go to your query dependencies view, it should look like this:

[image: Dependency View]

Notice that I've disabled load (to model) for the top 3 tables since we probably only need them as staging tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thus do a reference of the merged result (the merge of my two universes) and then do the specific steps in each of the references? But in this way, what will happen if I have new data in one of my excel universes? What if I do a refresh of one of my two starting file? What will happen in this case? Will this propagate in my ref? And If I add step to my merged file (like new conditional colummn) will it really propagate to my ref?

Comment: The data flows from top to bottom. Any changes in a table propagate to all of the ones below it. I recommend doing all of the steps that are common to the three Ref tables in the Merge table so you only have to do it once because, yes, it will propagate. A reference simply means start where the referenced query ended.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer and thank you for the discovery of the query dependency tool. This is really great! I will now also try to understand a bit better why someone would like to copy or duplicate. I think that duplicate is when someone does not want that change in the "original" query impacts the offspring.

Comment: Duplicate would be handy if, for example, you have two very similar queries but from different sources that you don't want to combine. Just duplicate one and make a couple of changes.